# 7407 functional schematic question

Tags: transistors, open-collector

I was trying to understand the role of the left-most transistor.

[image: 7404 functional schematic diagram]

... as illustrated in the datasheet:
[SNx407 and SNx417 Hex Buffers and Drivers With Open-Collector High-Voltage Outputs](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn7407.pdf)

If there is a '1' at Input A, it is possible that there will be insufficient potential difference for the transistor to be forward biased.  Additionally, the diode will be reverse-biased.  Therefore, this transistor doesn't appear to be doing a lot.

If there is a '0' at Input A, it seems to me that the left-most transistor will now be forward-biased.  However, I'm failing to understand how this affects the transistor, and the circuit generally, as the collector is connected to the base of the second from the left transistor.

How does the transistor, second from the left, move into being forward-biased?

Your wisdom is appreciated.

Comment: Please link to the source of the illustration you have used, if it's not your own work.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia TTL page likely explains this better, but when the input is low, the input stage BE junction is forward biased and no current flows from collector to the base of next transistor.

When input is high, the input transistor is in reverse active mode and some current flows from collector to base of next transistor, turning it on.

Comment: Thank you, @Justme for your help.

Comment: No, not "reverse active" mode -- current simply flows directly through the B-C junction to drive the base of the next transistor.

Comment: @DaveTweed, if there is no potential difference at the collector to the base of the next transistor, how does current flow?

Comment: @DaveTweed so when BC junction is forward biased, and BE junction is reverse biased, isn't that called the reverse active mode?

Comment: @Timothy: Why do you think there is no potential difference?

Comment: @Justme: Yes, but the circuit works even if the emitter is open-circuit. Most of the base current for the second transistor comes from the base of the first transistor.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I don't how it works.  That's why I'm asking questions and making observations.  You appear to know more than me about the topic therefore, whatever clarity you can provide, I'm appreciative.

Comment: @DaveTweed Ah yes, the good old "why can the transistor be thought as two diodes" applies here too, indeed the input could be floating so it won't be biased at all.

Comment: @Timothy: When the input is high (or open), current flows through the 6k, B-C of the first transistor, B-E of the second transistor, the 100r and the 1k to ground. Some of this current (supplemented with current from the 3.4k) also flows into the base the third transistor, turning it on, which cuts off the output transistor. For additional insight, try setting this circuit up in a simulator (CircuitLab is available right here) and looking at the voltages and currents throughout the circuit for different input voltages.

Comment: Thank you, @Justme.

Comment: Thank you, @DaveTweed.